# Alternative for strict-dynamic in unsupported browsers

Tags: safari, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

I have been working on implementing CSP for our web-application and have noticed that on [older browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=strict-dynamic), the following error is thrown:

```
Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.
```

Is there an alternative attribute I can use for browsers that do not yet support this property? Or, should I just remove it?

Comment: You shouldn’t drop `strict-dynamic`. The message in the question is expected behavior, & doesn’t indicate anything broken. The same message will appear whenever newer CSP keyword sources are introduced & used—because older browsers are naturally not gonna recognize them. See https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#strict-dynamic-usage. You can do `script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-abcdefg' 'strict-dynamic'`. In browsers that support `strict-dynamic` will ignore the`unsafe-inline` part. And in older browsers that don’t understand both `strict-dynamic` & `nonce`, then `unsafe-inline` will be used.

Comment: You can recommend your clients to use the new MS Edge Chromium browser. the new Edge browser is using a chromium browser engine and you will not get this error in it. For the older Edge browser, as it is not supported you will receive this error and I did not get any alternative attribute for it.